# Optimize an Active record query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Below query takes almost 300ms for some records in my table.

```
TestDescription.find(:first, :conditions =>["test_point_id IS NULL AND test_info=?",file_name])
```

is there any way I can improve its performance ???

Thanks!

Comment: Have you add index on columns like test_point_id AND test_info in your case?

Comment: @Salil  ...yes for test_point_id i have an index .... I will try adding it for test_info as well ...

Comment: @Salil ... test_info is a text field ...so am unable to create an index on that column .....

Comment: You can add it like creating migration and then `add_index :test_descriptions, :test_info` ref http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#M001438

Comment: @Salil ....adding a migration like this ...throws an error ..... that i cant create an index on this column ..... "BLOB/TEXT column 'test_info' used in key specification without a key length: CREATE  INDEX `test_info_index` ON `test_descriptions`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, drop the ancient `find(:first...)` syntax, and use

```
TestDescription.where(test_point_id: nil, test_info: file_name).first
```

Next, make sure you have indexes on the columns you're search against.

Comment: .....am unable to create an index on test_info field .... and changing the query to .where has not improved the performance much ....

Comment: You *can* add an index on your column, you just have to figure out how.

Comment: Thanks ...added the index like this.... create index test_info_index on test_descriptions(test_info(10));  ... now its fast, takes only 20 to 30ms :)